# Do some animals have a tolerance to the negative effects of inbreeding?

Tags: reproduction, sexual-reproduction

Are some animals more or less tolerant to inbreeding? By tolerant I mean do they have a genetic mechanism that allows them to inbreed and corrects for issues introduced through this? When I started searching for this I quickly ran into theories on how inbreeding is avoided but did not find information on whether some animals have genetic mechanisms that make them less likely to get negative effects from inbreeding.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by genetic mechanism? Do lethal recessives that prevent development and thus prevent offspring count?

Comment: @kmm I hadn't considered that, I was thinking of more of a self-correcting technique that would prevent to many occurrences of the same genetic markers from being chosen or just a level of fault tolerance where the critical mass of bad combinations is higher than most other vertebrates.

Comment: @kmm I'm not very well versed in biology but I was looking for something similar to how TP53 works in humans and elephants to prevent bad DNA copies. I was curious if such a mechanism existed in some animals at conception to prevent the negative mutations of inbreeding. I'm not sure if such a parallel mechanism exist but I figured if they can correct for bad copies that it would be possible to correct for too many pairs being duplicates or rather not enough entropy. Again sorry a lot of my terminology is a mix of computer science and what I remember from high school biology.